# Why are proxies distorted using proxy fitting with MbLab 1.7.8 in Blender 2.93

Tags: armature, proxies

I am giving this a new try with the hopes of someone knowing how to resolve this problem. This question is a refined version of the one I recently asked: [How can I fit a proxy to a model using MB-Lab?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226915/how-can-i-fit-a-proxy-to-a-model-using-mb-lab)

I have created a character using MB-Lab 1.7.8 in Blender 2.93 (yes I've upgraded since the last question). I am trying to fit proxies to the human object but it doesn't work as the picture below shows. First I applied any rotations/locations/scales to each and every object in the scene. I then set the origin to world origin just in case. However, whenever I try to fit the proxy on the characters body it gets distorted upwards and I fail to understand from where this distortion originates.

The image below shows the unfitted proxies as I've matched them to the shape of the character the way it should look when the proxies are fitted on the left - on the right you'll see what actually happens when I fit the proxies. I have tried all tricks in the book (that I'm aware of) and I've followed whatever Youtube tutorials that could be found out there, yet I can't get the proxies to fit as they should.

I'd be greatful if anybody could guide me as I'm eager to animate this character.

[image: Image showing the distortion when fitting proxies to my blender character]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this.

I learned from [this movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1InoQjSOvjE) that clothes can be derived from the body base mesh by duplicating certain areas of it and modifying it to resemble clothes. Inspired by this I began exploring how to transfer data from the base mesh to existing objects.

First I made two duplicates of the feet from the body mesh--one for each shoe. I then removed all but one vertice from both duplicates and joined each shoe to each remaining vertice. This transferred all shape keys and modifers from each remaining vertice to each shoe. I then removed the remaining vertices as these were not needed anymore.

I then transferred weights from the body mesh to each shoe and--voila--the shoes were finally stuck to the body in the right place without distortion.

When it comes to the rest of the clothing I've decided to derive them from duplicates of the body mesh as described in the above mentioned video. At last everything seems to work as it was originally intended.